# Strategy for Design-time Data in FlexBuilder

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I use data binding all over the place... but when I look at my app in the design view, the data bindings are either empty or show the binding expression.  In either case, it doesn't let me preview what my view will look like.

I have come up with one strategy: Create a "Design" state and populate the values with `text.Design="fake data"` or whatnot... but that becomes messy... I have to switch back and forth between visual states to get it all right.

There must be a better strategy?

Comment: Don't rely on binding, as it'll eventually give you performance headaches.  Also, don't rely on the Flex Builder Design view; run your application.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com: That sounds like old-school mentality.  I wouldn't develop any other way than with data binding.  It is powerful, and avoiding it is pre-mature optimization.  If there is an area that is a performance problem, then sure... optimize that away from data binding, but seriously?  The power of data binding is way too great to avoid.  Also, I am not RELYING on FlexBuilder design view... only using it as a tool to speed up my development cycles.  In both cases, I am doing things to speed up my development, not throttle it.

Comment: With Design view; I'm guilty as charged.  However, it sounds like you are organizing your code with the sole purpose of it working in design view. I think that is a long term flawed approach.  With Binding, I am "once bitten, twice shy."  I often solve performance problems and memory leaks for clients just by re-writing code that makes excessive use of Binding. Binding has it's place, for sure, but many use it blindly and some frameworks (Cairngorm at least) encourage poor binding practices. Binding is known to be a performance expensive operation and....

Comment: ... and it is often a nominal amount of work to use an alternative to binding to accomplish the same tasks.

Comment: I hear what you are saying with binding... I organize my code to be modular, testable and work with my designer (human), not for the designer (tool).  Data binding allows me to separate my view from my presentation logic and has yet to be a problem for me.  Anyways, I am just frustrated that when I go to the designer, I can't see how my data look.  In the Silverlight world, it is easy to inject "design-time" data so you can see what it looks like without running the app and getting into the right state. (they have better tools in general for this type of thing)  I am trying to find an analog.

Comment: Can you bind to a web service that gives you fake data for design time, and then change the biding to the real thing run time, or is there too many components involved?